# Is there something wrong with my react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack

I am practicing using react to build a simple table. Here my table has three columns. (name, job, delete). There is already some data in the table. In the third column, I want to build a button so the user can click and cancel the whole row

I already fixed several bugs but the table still does not show up

```jsx
const TableBody = props => { 
    const rows = props.fillTheData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.job}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const state = {
      character : [
              {
                  'name': 'Charlie',
                  'job': 'Janitor'
              },
              {
                  'name': 'Mac',
                  'job': 'Bouncer'
              },
              {
                  'name': 'Dee',
                  'job': 'Aspring actress'
              },
              {
                  'name': 'Dennis',
                  'job': 'Bartender'
              }
      ]
    }

    removeCharacter = index => {
        const {character} = this.state;

        this.setState({
          character: character.filter((element, i) => { 
              return i !== index;
          })
      });
    }

    return(

        <Table characters = {character} removeCharacter = {this.removeCharacter} />

    )
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {characters, removeCharacter} = this.props;
    return(
      <table>
        <TableHeader />
        <TableBody fillTheData = {characters} removeCharacter= {removeCharacter} />
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Right now, we have a cool Table component, but the data is being hard-coded. One of the big deals about React is how it handles data, and it does so with properties, referred to as props, and with state. First, we’ll focus on handling data with props.

Then let’s move all that data to an array of objects, as if we were bringing in a JSON-based API. We’ll have to create this array inside our render().

Comment: I am seeing you are using map index has a key, please don't use it, it's an anti pattern it will lead to unpredictable issues. check this https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not rendering the App component. To do this, you need to import the render method from the reactDOM library. So at the top of the file you would have something like:

`import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

At the end of the file you would render the App instance with: 
`ReactDOM.render(nodeWhereYouWillMount,<App />)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `state` is a local variable, and not persistent data of the App component. Try something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        character : [
            {
                'name': 'Charlie',
                'job': 'Janitor'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Mac',
                'job': 'Bouncer'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dee',
                'job': 'Aspring actress'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Dennis',
                'job': 'Bartender'
            }
        ]
    };

    removeCharacter = index => {
        const {character} = this.state;

        this.setState({
            character: character.filter((element, i) => { 
                return i !== index;
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Table characters = {this.state.character} removeCharacter = {this.removeCharacter} />
        )
    }
}
```

Notice we've defined `state={character: [...]};` outside the render() method, and later use `characters = {this.state.character}` to read it back. Now when the removeCharacter() method is called, it will change data that exists outside of the render() method.

Comment: Ideally, state should be declared inside constructor

Comment: @Rajesh maybe. That would be required if the state is dynamic or dependant on something else like this one: `this.state = {date: new Date()};`

Comment: You just have 1 object as state. Objects are copied as reference. So if you have more than 1 component's instance, you are basically sharing the state which will give you adverse results.

Comment: Yes. The code work. Previously, I declared the variable in the wrong scope. Thank you guys!